# Arduino Uno PIR Motion Sensor Using Twilio

Tags: arduino, sms, twilio, sensors, ethernet

I am doing a college project using an Arduino Uno, Ethernet shield and a motion sensor. I have never worked with Arduino before. When something passes the motion sensor I want to show that it did by sending a notification to a cloud communication service like Twilio and then use Twilio to send an SMS to a mobile phone to say that it detected movement. I'm not to sure where to start researching for this one or even if it is at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Good luck with the project. I'd start researching it with the series of blog posts that my colleague Greg wrote earlier this year. They chart his progress from starting with an Arduino Yún to teaching his dog how to send selfies. I know it's not the same as an Arduino Uno, but I'm sure most of the theory and code still applies. Check out the series here:

- [Getting started with the Arduino Yun – the Arduino with WiFi](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/arduino-wifi-getting-started-arduino-yun.html)
- [Build a Photobooth with an Arduino Yun, a Webcam and Dropbox](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/arduino-powered-photobooth-arduino-yun-a-webcam-and-dropbox.html)
- [Send SMS And MMS From Your Arduino Yun](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/send-sms-and-mms-from-your-arduino-yun.html)
- [How I Taught My Dog to Text Me Selfies](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/03/how-my-dog-sends-selfies.html)